# How to set NSInteger in HTTPHeaderField in AFnetworking

Tags: ios, iphone, web-services, rest, afnetworking-2

I want to set NSInteger value in HTTPHeaderField. Below is my code

```
NSInteger user_id =1234;
if ([AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager].reachable) {

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *afRequestOpManager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    afRequestOpManager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    afRequestOpManager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    [afRequestOpManager.requestSerializer setValue:user_id forHTTPHeaderField:@"user-id"];
    [afRequestOpManager PUT:strUrl parameters:nil success: ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
     {
         NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
     }failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
         NSLog(@"JSON: %ld", error.code);
     }];
```

But i am not able to set user_id as integer.

Comment: Why are you trying to set User_ID in HeaderField.....??

Comment: - (void)setValue:(NSString *)value forHTTPHeaderField:(NSString *)field; 
value is NSString not NSInterger try convert it.

Answer (score 0):

The type which is passed into setValue: is NSString. In order to convert your NSInteger to NSString, use this: `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)user_id]`

Comment: No,I want to send it as integer becoz at server side they accepting as integer.

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP Headers values can only take string values, it cannot have any other data type values,

So convert your user id to string as below

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",user_id]
```

Then set the Value in the headers , also just for convention , always prefix your custom http headers with **X-** so ur header will become X-user-id

Comment: No,I want to send it as integer becoz at server side they accepting as integer.

Comment: you cant, it is how http request header fields are made, it is not an limitation with any specific language, you can only send string value in http headers, you have to change how you handle it in server side, convert from string to integer